# Storing data from API in JSON format in incremental manner

Tags: python, json, python-requests, databricks

I am trying to request this API and store data in incremental manner in datalake.

This is the API I am trying to source : [Get Bee messages](https://docs.roambee.com/#tag/Bee/operation/Get%20Bee%20Messages)

Code:

```
import requests

import json
import os

url = "https://api.roambee.com/bee/bee_messages"

dir_path = "/dbfs/jhgfd/adata/dfs/roambee/raw/api_responses_get_bee_messages/"

headers = {
    "apikey": "rtyrewrERTYUIOLIKJHGFRDSASDERFTGYHUJKILJHGFtyujhtrewsadfgh",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
 bid_list = ["3456,12345,12345,2345,2345,2345,2345,2345,345,3456"]


  for bid in bid_list:
   params = {
    "bid": bid,
    "start": "1690848000000",
    "days": 10
   }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

bee_data = response.json()

response_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f"response_data_{bid}.json")
if os.path.exists(response_file_path):
    # If the file exists, load existing data and append new data
    with open(response_file_path, "r") as response_file:
        existing_data = json.load(response_file)
    existing_data.extend(bee_data)
    bee_data = existing_data

if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
    os.makedirs(dir_path)

with open(response_file_path, "w") as response_file:
    json.dump(bee_data, response_file)

print(f"Response data for BID {bid} saved in:", response_file_path)


delta_table_path = "/mnt/analyticsdata/rms/roambee/raw/api_responses_get_bee_messages/response_data_868199058105959.json"
first_bee_test = spark.read.format("json").load(delta_table_path)

display(first_bee_test)
```

this code returns a data like this [google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZ-VOa9iomFGisMHUbZhLmq3mc2VPO_35vV3vtXmLaw/edit?usp=sharing) date:
`10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,11` date, ideally it should be date:  `11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` any idea how to get data in required format? goal is to refresh above code every day and get latest 10 day of data EXTENDED TO EXISTING FILE.

i have converted epoc time to human readable date

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a format that allows iteration / appending. You must load an entire JSON every time in order for it to be valid.

You may pre-sort and use [JSON-lines](https://jsonlines.org/) as an alternative, where each line is a JSON object, or CSV.

Comment: can you please suggest or modify a code as per this line ? `You may pre-sort and use JSON-lines as an alternative, where each line is a JSON object, or CSV.

`